# Express.js: CORS policy blocking Stripe API request

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to send form data from React/Redux to a locally hosted Express.js server. However, I am getting CORS errors:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4000/api/donate' from
 origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response
 to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-
Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

VM6535:1 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin
 response http://localhost:4000/api/donate with MIME type text/html. See 
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

createError.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
```

This was the initial CORS policy I set to have Express.js receive my React Data:

```
// index.js in the backend project
let cors = require("cors");

const corsOptions = {origin : "http://localhost:3000/" }; // React app is on port 3000

router.post('/api/donate', cors(corsOptions), (req, res, next) => { ....
```

I was sending test credit card charges to Stripe using string data before and it worked with no errors. Only difference now is that before I was only sending data using form/input components from `react-stripe-elements` whereas now I also send some data from my Redux store.

Even now with this error, Stripe still responds with partial token data (maybe default values, not sure).

Is something missing with my CORS policy? I thought whitelisting localhost:3000 would have fixed it, and it appeared to. But it is still issuing the error above.

Comment: Preflight request has a method `OPTIONS` so add a middle-ware to intercept all request and check for http method if it's `OPTIONS` then return the response status `200`. For reference follow this guide-  https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: Thanks. I took a look at that guide and it appears to allow the origin of the React app as shown in my code sample; am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

CORB is a new policy enforced by certain browsers. It enforces the idea of did I get back what I requested. so if you make a response with JSON headers and you get back text/html like you did in this case then chrome will eat the response and throw the second error you see. change your content headers to text/html and it will probably work for you.